# Select newly created elements on page - puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I can't select newly created elements made by JS after I process selected task, let's say click on button. Exmp: obr.[image] .

How can you see I click on button and JS adds new `<tr>` to current table. This `<tr>` can't be seen even with

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML)
```

even I tryed to wait

```
await page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout: 2000 });
```

also with/without parametr visibility: true.

Is there a way to research content or get changed dom?
Thank you for help

Comment: A [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) can help you watch changes to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) with only `childList` option `true`. Something like this:

```js
const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
const observerConfig = { childList: true };
const observerCallback = (mutationsList, observer) => {
    for(const mutation of mutationsList)
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => console.log(node));
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(observerCallback);
observer.observe(table, observerConfig);

// sample code just for adding new rows
const btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  const tr = document.createElement("TR");
  const td = document.createElement("TD");
  td.innerText = "I'm new";
  tr.append(td);
  table.append(tr);
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="myBtn">Add</button>
```

Comment: thank you for answer, I am going to try it later in the day, but it looks great

Comment: I need it to little improve it but is definitely true. For my use I use it config = { characterData: true, attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true }

Comment: @x-magix Yep, depends on what you need. I'm glad it helps.